# Dropbox installation on linux server not working

Tags: linux, dropbox, dedicated-server

I'm trying to install dropbox on my dedicated server in order to backup the database but when I run `tar -tzf dropbox.tar.gz` I keep getting this error and haven't been able to find a solution.

Error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

cmd runned:

```
wget -O dropbox.tar.gz "http://www.dropbox.com/download/?plat=lnx.x86"
tar -tzf dropbox.tar.gz
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me, however the contents of the tar file were extracted to a folder called `.dropbox-dist` which is hidden on Unix because the name of the directory begins with a `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a tarball. Verify that the file downloaded properly.

Comment: ok. I've managed to run "tar -tzf dropbox.tar.gz " but now when I run "~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd" to link my account I get this error:"/lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
"...Never mind.fixed this.